# Cannot access shared drive in same machine uisng machine name but can access using IP

Tags: networking, network-shares, file-sharing, hosts-file

I have 4 desktops running Windows Server 2008 32bit version.

I created some shares in all these machines. My program gets files from these machines (like `\machine1\abcd`). The machine names mentioned in the program and the actual machine names doesn't match and I can't change either program or machine names.

So I mapped the machine name used by the program to the local IP address of the machine using "hosts" file. Everything works fine, but, when I try to access a share in a machine using local machine's name, Windows asks for a username and password. (I tried entering username and password but its not working). But when I try to access the same share using local machine's IP address, its opening.

Let my machine names be **m1**, **m2**, **m3**, **m4** and my program refers to them as `mb01`, `mb02`, `mb03`, `mb04`.

When I try to access a share in `mb01` from mb01(m1) as `\\mb01\share1`, Windows asks for username and password. When try to access shares in other machines everything works perfectly.

I want to access share in local machine without getting prompted for password. How can I achieve that?
Edit 1: I am actually using as \\mb01\share1. Typo in question.

Comment: how about \\mb01\share1 - double slashes

Answer (score 0):

I just asked a similar question, and someone was able to give an answer that worked!  See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1016319/access-shares-on-my-computer-using-different-computer-name/1016344#1016344) question.

Specifically, you add the registry entry described in this [WindowsITPro article](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/how-can-i-define-multiple-netbios-names-machine), then just restart the Server service.

You cannot ping, because this is strictly a NetBIOS thing, not a TCP/IP thing, but you can now get to your shares using the 'alias' name.