# Access shares on my computer using different computer name

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I'm running Windows 10 Pro on a home network.  No domain.

Background:  As a developer, I use source control for my projects.  I have *many* projects.  They all reference the source control location like this:  \sol\Data\SourceSafe.  Now, SOL was my terastation (NAS).  It died.  All the data is now on my local PC called VAL.  So my source control location is now \\VAL\Data\SourceSafe.  However, I really really want to avoid changing that in all my projects.

Goal:  I want to use some kind of trickery in order to have VAL respond as SOL, and thereby have \\SOL\Data\SourceSafe work again as if it has not changed physical location.

**What I've tried so far**

I've added an entry in my hosts file using the IP address of my computer, VAL:

```
10.107.1.133     sol
```

I can now ping sol successfully.

However, inspite of having the 'alias' in place for the host name, I cannot use the Data share.

```
dir \\val\data\SourceSafe --> works
dir \\sol\data\SourceSafe --> The user name or password is incorrect
dir \\sol\data --> same
```

Mapping a drive letter and explicitly specifying my username and password (when prompted)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use * \\sol\data /user:swatt
Enter the password for 'swatt' to connect to 'sol':
System error 86 has occurred.

The specified network password is not correct.
```

I have also tried adding the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry and rebooting, but no change.

So, how can I make the \\sol\data\SourceSafe path work again?

Thanks much!
Sandra

Comment: Have you considered just changing your computer MS Network ID to SOL? If I remember correctly - NetBIOS names resulution is realized trough lmhosts file, so try add 10.107.1.133 SOL to lmhosts...

Comment: It's not really a problem with name resolution, as I can ping sol now.  But I tried the lmhosts entry instead of the hosts entry, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not change your machine name to SOL instead, or is VAL important?

Alternatively, is there a reason you don't want to change it in your projects? It would surely just be a quick find and replace across all files?

Otherwise, I believe you'd need your own DNS server to handle it, or you could try this:

http://windowsitpro.com/networking/how-can-i-define-multiple-netbios-names-machine

Comment: I'd prefer not to change my machine name since other machines at home access shares on it.  I'm not having a problem pinging SOL, so not sure how DNS would help me.  I'll do search-and-replace if no other solution is found.  I'll check out that article, though it's from 1999, so not having high hopes for Windows 10.  :)

Comment: Well I'll be.  LOL  The registry edit in the WindowsITPro article from 1999 worked.  You don't have to restart the machine, just the Server service.